# OnLongClickListener of parent view never called. How to trigger it?

Tags: android

I have a parent Linear which is a container view for a custom control which is a third party component.
I think that the child (third party component) is overriding or using somehow the OnTouchListener for his purposes and for this reason somehow the parent OnLongClickListener is never triggered even if correctly set. Even the OnLongClickListener of the child is never triggered.
I don't want to go inside the third party component and do expecially changes for my purposes but is there a different way to trigger the OnLongClickListener of the container if I long click in his area even if the child is doing his job. I'm the parent and I think that the parents should educate their children!

Comment: When child is smaller then the parent I don't think it's the case.
Set the onTouch listener and check if you have any callbacks there. When this doesn't work you can try to add a new transparent layout over everything and catch onLongPress there.

Comment: The parent smaller? What do you mean. No the parent is just a container. His size is the same as the child. I just wanna to add another feature to the child third party component without the need to dig into the component source code. I hate to dig in the other's code.

Comment: I thought that the container is bigger then the child and you try to longpress on the free space. So when the thirdPartyComponent.setOnClickListener doesn't work fine, try setOnTouchListener, when this still doesn't work make a transparent overlay workaround. Use Relative layout, put a thirdParttComponent child and then any transparent view which will handle the long press.

Comment: So the answer is : "use a relativelayout instead of a Linear". I'm able to use setOnTouchListener of the child but don't know how can I emulate the onlongClick.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner view is consuming the touch event then they will not be returned to your container, which is the reason your click listeners aren't working.

You can override this by implementing a custom container, and overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent()` method on it, and calling to both the super implementation and your `onTouchEvent()` method from there. This should make your click listeners work.

The following is the code for the container, which you can use in the place of your `LinearLayout`:

```
public class ClickHandlingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private boolean touchEventCalled;

    public ClickHandlingLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ClickHandlingLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ClickHandlingLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean isHandled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if (isHandled && !touchEventCalled) {
            onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        touchEventCalled = false;
        return isHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        touchEventCalled = true;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

}

Comment: I almost understand but do you have a basic example for it ?